# Density estimation using (different) order statistics

Tags: kernel-smoothing, order-statistics, density-estimation

I need to estimate a univariate distribution $F$ as flexibly as possible. However, I do not observe draws from $F$ directly. Each observation $x_i$ is the minimum of $a_i$ draws from $F$, where $a_i$ is a known number from 2 to 5 that varies across observations.

I know how to solve this problem with $a_i=a$ fixed across observations. Kernel density estimation could find $F_{(1:a)}$, from which $F$ follows by

$F_{(1:a)}(x)^{1/a}=F(x)$

So the question is how $F$ can be estimated specifically when $a_i$ varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to estimate the CDF by maximum likelihood. The output is a step function which can be kernel smoothed.

## Estimation

For every $x$ choose $F(x)$ to maximize the log-likelihood

$\sum_a A_{ax} \log((1-F(x))^a) + B_{ax} \log(1-(1-F(x))^a)$

where for observations with $a_i=a$ $A_{ax}$ is the number of such observations above $x$ and $B_{ax}$ is the number below x.

The first order condition is

$0=\sum_a A_{ax} a (1-F(x))^{-1} - B_{ax} a \frac{(1-F(x))^{a-1}}{1-(1-F(x))^a}$

which can be solved numerically (I used Julia's `fzero`). The solutions $F(x)$ form a step function akin to an empirical CDF. Optionally, follow up with a kernel smoother to to recover a smooth estimate of $F$.

## Results

Assume $F \sim$ Weibull(2,2) for testing. With 20,000 observations the maximum likelihood estimate is close to the true distribution.

[image: cdf20k]

Results are tolerable with 200 observations.

[image: cdf200]

## Julia code

```
using Distributions
using Roots
using DataFrames
using Plots
srand(1111)

n = 200
a = rand(2:5,n)

dist=Weibull(2,2)

all_draws = rand(dist,sum(a))

x = fill(NaN,n)
k = 1
for i=1:n
  draws = all_draws[k:(k+a[i]-1)]
  k += a[i]
  x[i] = minimum(draws)
end

x=reshape(x,length(x),1)
df = convert(DataFrame,x)
rename!(df, :x1, :x)
df[:a] = a
sort!(df, cols=:x)

above = collect(countmap(df[:a]))
sort!(above, by=x->x[1])
above = vcat(map(t -> [t[2]], values(above))...)
below = convert(Array{Int,1},zeros(size(above)))

function foc(one_min_F,above,below)
  ret=0
  for a=2:5
    ret += above[a-1]*a/one_min_F
    ret -= below[a-1]*a*one_min_F^(a-1)/(1-one_min_F^a)
   end
  return ret
end

one_min_F=fill(NaN,n-1)
for i=1:n-1
  tmp = df[i,:a]-1
  above[tmp] -= 1
  below[tmp] += 1
  one_min_F[i] = fzero(x->foc(x,above,below),1e-30,1-1e-30)
end

F=1.-one_min_F

scatter(df[1:end-1,:x],F,label="estimated CDF")
plot!(df[1:end-1,:x],t->cdf(dist,t),label="theoretical CDF")
```